# jQuery UI slider: how do I make slider handle collisions work nicely at min/max values?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

https://codepen.io/ophello/pen/BaNaPdp?editors=0010

I have a jquery.ui slider set up with two handles at once, and an offset implementation that allows them to collide and push each other.

But, if you whip the mouse quickly to one end with both sliders, the last recorded values get stuck at whatever value they were when the mouse exits the range. How do I fix this?

This is the code to handle the collisions:

```js
if (ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1]) {
    if ($(ui.handle).index() == 0) { // if the left handle is being dragged
        ui.values[0] = ui.value + offset;
        ui.values[1] = ui.value + offset + 1;
        $(this).slider("values", 1, ui.value + 1 + offset * 2);
    } else {
        ui.values[0] = ui.value - offset - 1;
        ui.values[1] = ui.value - offset;
        $(this).slider("values", 0, ui.value - 1 - offset * 2);
    }
}
```

And this is stops the handles from colliding when one of the values is maxed out:

```js
if (ui.values[0] < 1 && ui.values[1] < 1) {
    ui.values[0] = 0; // why doesn't this work at high speeds?
    ui.values[1] = 1; // why doesn't this work at high speeds?
    $(this).slider("values", 1, 1 + offset);
    return false;
} else if (ui.values[0] > yMax - 1 && ui.values[1] > yMax) {
    ui.values[0] = yMax - 1; // why doesn't this work at high speeds?
    ui.values[1] = yMax;     // why doesn't this work at high speeds?
    $(this).slider("values", 0, yMax - 1 - offset);
    return false;
}
```

I cannot get the final slider values to reset to their min values! When you quickly slide both sliders to the right or left together, the values should finish at 0-1 or 99-100. But you'll get random results if you do this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working, even the lines you commented that do nothing. If you return out of the function after that line, it will work as you intended.

```js
$(function() {
  var offset = 3;
  var x = 45;
  var y = 55;
  var yMax = 100;

  $("#value").val(x + " – " + y);

  $("#slider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 0 - offset, // apply offset to address handle collision
    step: 1,
    max: yMax + offset, // apply offset
    values: [x - offset, y + offset], // apply offset
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      ui.values[0] = ui.values[0] + offset; // apply offset
      ui.values[1] = ui.values[1] - offset;

      // collision/push handler
      if (ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1]) {
        if ($(ui.handle).index() == 0) {
          ui.values[0] = ui.value + offset;
          ui.values[1] = ui.value + offset + 1;
          $(this).slider("values", 1, ui.value + 1 + offset * 2);
        } else {
          ui.values[0] = ui.value - offset - 1;
          ui.values[1] = ui.value - offset;
          $(this).slider("values", 0, ui.value - 1 - offset * 2);
        }
      }

      // replace the section below with this to see the other behavior
      // if (ui.values[0] < 0 || ui.values[1] > yMax) { return false }

      if (ui.values[0] < 1 && ui.values[1] <= 1) {
        ui.values[0] = 0
        ui.values[1] = 1
        // this is supposed to tell the RIGHT slider handle to STOP MOVING 
        // by setting its value to 1, but it doesn't do ANYTHING
        $(this).slider("values", 1, 1 + offset); // why doesn't this line do anything???
        return false;
      } else if (ui.values[0] > yMax - 1 && ui.values[1] > yMax) {
        ui.values[0] = yMax - 1
        ui.values[1] = yMax
        // this is supposed to tell the LEFT slider handle to STOP MOVING 
        // by setting its value to 1, but it doesn't do ANYTHING
        $(this).slider("values", 0, yMax - 1 - offset); // why doesn't this line do anything???
        return false;
        
      }

      // if (ui.values[0] < 0 || ui.values[1] > yMax) { return false }

      // Try commenting out the above section and replacing
      // it with this one line to see a closer version of the
      // intended behavior. The problem with this implementation
      // is that it misbehaves when the mouse is flicked outside
      // the slider area while pushing both sliders together.





      // update displayed diameter values
      $("#value").val(ui.values[0] + " – " + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input {
  font-size: 13px;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  color: #f6931f;
  text-align: left;
}

#container {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0 25px;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.ui-slider {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  height: 19px;
  width: 11px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="value" readonly style="width:75px">
  <div id="slider" style="width:212px;height:11px;"></div>

  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly...the numbers still get stuck at weird values if you race off towards the right or left as they collide together. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks in part to Mouser!

The problem with "return false" is that it halts the entire slider process until it detects another movement. Therefore, I need to make sure my code forces the conditions I want before calling that function. I force the display and values to match the intended result, then call the return function. See my original post's link to see it working!